# Run a function before a model is saved to the database in DataMapper ORM and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

Is there a way to run a function/callback before a model is saved using Datamapper ORM in CodeIgniter?

I know this is possible in most ORMs where you can hook into certain points such as before_update, before_create and so on. Basically I want to hook into before_update to save a copy of the table row in another logging table before it is modified. I am doing this in the controller currently but want to move it into the model as a better MVC practice.

Please provide code or link to documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Datamapper has a decent documentation on cloning/copying: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/clonecopy.html

I would probably set up a separate Log_model for those tasks. You can load one model from another by instantiating CI (`$this->CI =& get_instance();`) and then loading the Log_model from your data model.

Comment: Thanks, yes the Datamapper documentation is fantastic. I like your idea, will see how it goes.